# Pull only one category from tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making two web pages one for SHOES and the other for BOOTS. 
I would like to fetch all the shoes for one page and then all the boots for the second page.

So basically I would like to know how I can list all the products from one category from my tables.

First table

```
product_id, name, desc, price, qty, cat_id
```

Second table

```
cat_id, cat_name
```

In the result, I would look like to have the below details.

```
Boots
Name      Desc    Price   Qty

Shoes
Name      Desc    Price   Qty
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.cat_id = Table2.cat_id
AND Table2.cat_name = "Boots"


SELECT * 
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.cat_id = Table2.cat_id
AND Table2.cat_name = "Shoes"
```

Comment: @user3076198 You are very welcome...  if any of the answers on the page were helpful, PLEASE up vote them, and accept one of the answers as "accepted".   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*,  t2.cat_name
FROM first_table t1
LEFT JOIN second_table t2 ON t1.cat_id = t2.id
WHERE t1.cat_id = {the cat id for shoes or boots}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a few assumptions about your table names:

```
$pdo = new PDO(); // Insert your connection string here
$pdo->prepare("SELECT products.* FROM products LEFT JOIN categories ON products.cat_id = categories.cat_id WHERE cat_name = :Cateory");
$pdo->bindParam(":Category", $category);
$pdo->execute();
$data = $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```